# Disabled button for input file .NET Razor

Tags: razor

I need the user to be able to upload a file, and once the file is uploaded I need for the submit button to become enabled. I have this code but for some reason its not working.

```
                @using (Html.BeginForm("UploadChangedDocument", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                {
                    @Html.Hidden("documentId", item.DocumentId)
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="file" class="control-label col-md-4">Upload Edited Document:</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8 upload-block">
                            <input type="file" name="file" id="InputFile" />
                        </div>
                        <br />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="file" class="control-label col-md-4">Submit Edited Document:</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8 upload-block">
                            <button id="upload-btn" type="button blue-button" class="btn blue-button" disabled="">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                }
```

This is my Jquery Code

```
<script>
    $('.upload-block input').change(function () {
        $('#upload-btn').prop('disabled', !($('#InputFile').val()));
    });
</script>
```

Is there something wrong with this code? Is there a better way to do this? By uploading a document, the #InputFile would obtain a value enabling the Submit button, right?

I should also add that this is being generated for many documents so each document should have the ability to be downloaded edited and submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody looking for a way of eitering through documents editing them and uploading them here is a formula you can use

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadChangedDocument", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                {
                    @Html.Hidden("documentId", item.DocumentId)
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="file" class="control-label col-md-4">Upload Edited Document:</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input type="file" name="file" id="InputFile-@count.ToString()" />

                        </div>
                        <br />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="file" class="control-label col-md-4">Submit Edited Document:</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input id="upload-btn-@count.ToString()" type="submit" class="btn blue-button" disabled="" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <script>
                        $(document).ready(
                            function () {
                                $('#InputFile-@count.ToString()').change(
                                    function () {
                                        if ($(this).val()) {
                                            $('#upload-btn-@count.ToString()').attr('disabled', false);
                                            // or, as has been pointed out elsewhere:
                                            // $('input:submit').removeAttr('disabled'); 
                                        }
                                    }
                                );
                            });
                    </script>
                }
```